# Azure Failover Groups and IdentityDbContext

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-identity, high-availability, failover

Having a strange issue with Azure Failover Groups for our DB, and IdentityDbContext (AspNet Identity).

If I set the connection string to the failover group, I receive a login failed error in the logs, however if I connect directly to the primary or secondary servers, the login succeeds.

The other strange part is that this only seems to happen with IdentityDbContext.  If I use just a normal DB context for a test, the login works fine with the failover group connection string, if I use new SqlConnection, it also works fine, but when I try to use IdentityDbContext -> Login failed.

I know when connecting to a failover group from SSMS, you need to specify a default DB since it has no access to master, but in my connection string I have a DB specified so I'm not sure if that could be the problem.

Has anyone else encountered this? I feel like it's strange that this would only be happening to myself.

This is in .NET 4.6.1 with the latest version of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity (2.2.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found the issue thanks to this blog post:

http://www.morganskinner.com/2014/04/optimizing-aspnet-identity-database.html

Even though technically the blog post has nothing to do with Failover groups, it does point out the fact that IdentityDbContext does a check against sys.databases and other "master" db operations which are unavailable in the Failover group.

So the reason it was working with normal DBContexts, and SqlConnections was because theses hidden checks were not being performed. A

Since I don't need the IdentityDbContext to do these checks, simply setting the second parameter of the base call to **false** in order to by pass this functionality solved the issue.

Ex: `public AuthenticationContext(): base(<connection string id>,false)`

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I have create a test demo on my side, it works well.

I used the failover group url as the connection string and it could login and register user successfully.

I guess you may set the wrong connection string.

I suggest you could follow below connectionstring and test again.

```
Server=tcp:{yourfailover group name}.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog={the database name};Persist Security Info=False;User ID={user name};Password={password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

I also use identity 2.2.1 and net 4.6.1 MVC application.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, this is indeed how the connection string already looks, so it does not fix the issue.